# How to update expo app block after getting data from database?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm trying to connect database with my expo app. I used react redux to get data from database and when data is loaded i need to update my furniture block with data i got. But when i'm getting data nothing happens. What an I doing wrong?

```
const dispatch = useDispatch()
const furniture = useSelector((state) => state.furniture.furniture)

const isFurnitureLoading = furniture.status == 'loading'

React.useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(fetchFurniture())
 }, [])
```

```
{isFurnitureLoading ? null : furniture.items.map((obj, index) =>
 {
  <FurnitureBox
  name = {obj.name}
  price = {obj.price}
  imgsrc = {require("../assets/img-main-page/computer_table.png")}
  navigation={navigation} 
  navigation_page="Product_page_1"
 />
 } 
)}
```

I haven't found any information about this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing is returned from the `furniture.items.map` callback function body.

Return valid JSX from the map callback function. ***Don't*** forget to include a React key for each mapped element/component.

Use an ***explicit*** return statement from the function body

```
{isFurnitureLoading
  ? null
  : furniture.items.map((obj) => {
      return (
        <FurnitureBox
          key={obj.name}
          name={obj.name}
          price={obj.price}
          imgsrc={require("../assets/img-main-page/computer_table.png")}
          navigation={navigation} 
          navigation_page="Product_page_1"
        />
      );
    } 
)}
```

or use an ***implicit*** return using the arrow function

```
{isFurnitureLoading
  ? null
  : furniture.items.map((obj) => (
      <FurnitureBox
        key={obj.name}
        name={obj.name}
        price={obj.price}
        imgsrc={require("../assets/img-main-page/computer_table.png")}
        navigation={navigation} 
        navigation_page="Product_page_1"
      />
    ) 
)}
```